# Array of numbers has two extra space in between

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have two mappings file like this as shown below:

**primary-mapping.txt**

```
{1=[343, 0, 686, 1372, 882, 196], 2=[687, 1, 1373, 883, 197, 736, 1030, 1569], 3=[1374, 2, 884, 737, 198, 1570], 4=[1375, 1032, 1424, 3, 885, 1228], 5=[1033, 1425, 4, 200, 886]}
```

**secondary-mapping.txt**

```
{1=[1152, 816, 1488, 336, 1008], 2=[1153, 0, 817, 337, 1489, 1009, 1297], 3=[1, 1154, 1490, 338], 4=[1155, 2, 339, 1491, 819, 1299, 1635], 5=[820, 1492, 340, 3, 1156]}
```

In the above mapping files, each `clientId` has primary and secondary mapping. For example: `clientId 1` has `343, 0, 686, 1372, 882, 196` primary mapping and `1152, 816, 1488, 336, 1008` secondary mapping. Similarly for other `clientIds` as well.

Below is my shell script in which it prints primary and secondary mapping for a particular clientid:

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfiles=(primary-mapping.txt secondary-mapping.txt)

mappingsByClientID () {
  (($# != 3)) && { echo "Insufficient arguments" >&2; exit 1; }
  declare -n arr=$1
  id=$2
  file=${mapfiles[$3]}

  if ! grep -q "[{ ]$id=" "$file"; then
      echo "Couldn't find mapping for id '$id' in file '$file'" >&2
      exit 1
  fi
  mapfile -t arr < <(sed -r "s/.*[{ ]$id=\[([^]\]+).*/\1/" "$file" | tr -s , '\n')
  if ((${#arr[@]} == 0)); then
      echo "Couldn't find mapping for id '$id' in file '$file'" >&2
      exit 1
  fi
}

mappingsByClientID pri 3 0
mappingsByClientID sec 3 1

echo "primary files: ${pri[@]}"
echo "secondary files: ${sec[@]}"
```

Now when I print out `pri` and `sec` array I am seeing an extra space between each elements in the array. Meaning each element has two spaces between them. I am not sure what's wrong here. It looks to me something is off with `sed` line I believe. 
For example, primary files array is getting printed out like this:

`1220  1374  415  1097  1219  557  401`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip the spaces along with comma in the `tr` call:

```
mapfile -t arr < <(sed -r "s/.*[{ ]$id=\[([^]\]+).*/\1/" "$file" | tr -s '[ ,]' '\n')
```